# Unity and constructors

Tags: unity-container, multiple-constructors

Is it possible to make unity try all defined constructors starting with the one with most arguments down to the least specific one (the default constructor)?

**Edit**

What I mean:

```
foreach (var constructor in concrete.GetConstructorsOrderByParameterCount())
{
   if(CanFulfilDependencies(constructor))
   {
       UseConstructor(constructor);
       break;
   }
}
```

I don't want Unity to only try the constructor with most parameters. I want it to continue trying until it finds a suitable constructor. If Unity doesn't provide this behavior by default, is it possible to create an extension or something to be able to do this?

**Edit 2**

I got a class with two constructors:

```
public class MyConcrete : ISomeInterface
{
    public MyConcrete (IDepend1 dep, IDepend2 dep2)
    {}

    public MyConcrete(IDepend1 dep)
    {}
}
```

The class exists in a library which is used by multiple projects. In this project I want to use **second** constructor. But Unity stops since it can't fulfill the dependencies by the first constructor. And I do *not* want to change the class since the first constructor is used by DI in other projects.

Hence the need for Unity to try resolving all constructors.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "try"?

Comment: Again...you say "suitable"...please provide some code where this problem is surfacing as it may make things more clear. Constructors shouldn't depend in general on external entities outside of what is being passed in, shouldn't throw Exceptions, etc... Edited my answer however...

Comment: Does it need to be automatic (and therefore unpredictable) or can you use the container api instead to tell it what constructor to call?

Comment: @chris, you have different constructors for a reason. It's just as unpredictable as if you created the class yourself by choosing one of the constructors. Always want to use the same injection? Then create only one constructor..

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant it's unpredictable because if you just have the container "try them all", what order does it try them in? What happens if you disagree with that order? In this case, why can't you just say, when you set up your container in project2, "container.RegisterType<ISomeInterface, MyConcrete>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IDepend1)));" and remove all the ambiguity? (Or the equivalent in the config file if that's what you're using.) No need to change the code in your library, just a little more config on the container.

Comment: First of all.I do not understand why I have to motivate WHY i want to do this. It's getting tiresome. Ok if you have written an answer like "You can do it like this: XXXXX, but I really suggest that you don't because of XXXXXX". I've been developing for 15 years and do have enough experience to know of any problems that this can cause. I've actually written a IoC container myself that do exactly this without having any problems during the 3 years I've used it. Using Unity was not my choice but my clients. The order of constructors is of course trying the one with most parameters first desc.

Comment: I'm asking WHY because in MY 20 years of experience, when somebody's asking how to do something specific its usually because they've jumped to a solution, and pushing on the why gets back to the actual problem, which opens up other possibilities. I'm trying to help, honest.

Comment: As for the actual implementation, unless you are familiar with IL Emit and dynamic codegen in C#, it's very, very hard. If you are, it's just very hard. It's trivial to tell the container to try a specific constructor, but the logic's not set up for running multiple constructors one after the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity will choose the constructor with the most parameters unless you explicitly tag a constructor with the `[InjectionConstructor]` attribute which would then define the constructor for Unity to use.

When you state a suitable constructor; that is somewhat contingent on the environment. If for instance you always want to guarantee that a certain constructor is used when making use of Unity use the attribute mentioned previously, otherwise explicitly call the constructor you want to use.

What would be the point of Unity "trying" all constructors? It's purpose is to provide an instance of a type in a decoupled manner. Why would it iterate through the constructors if any constructor will create an instance of the type?

**EDIT:**

You could allow the constructor with the most params to be used within the project that does not have a reference to that type within its container by making use of a [child container](http://www.pnpguidance.net/Post/UnityNestedContainersIUnityParentContainerCreateChildContainer.aspx). This will not force the use of the constructor with a single param but it will allow the constructor with 2 params to work across the projects now.

You could also switch to using the single constructor across the board and force the other interface in via another form of DI (Property Injection), not Constructor Injection...therefore the base is applicable across the projects which would make more sense.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify something: the attribute is one was of telling the container which constructor to call. You can also use the api or the config file. Either of them are preferable to the attribute.

Comment: @Chris I'm a fan of attribute tags to some degree. Perhaps a constructor is called only for testing and you don't want Unity to ever call it...tag the explicit constructor and bypass Unity during the unit tests.

Comment: I do that via container config rather than attributes, ideally. Attributes couple the code to the container, and it also means that I, as the class author, am making an assumption for every user of my class that isn't really mine to make.

Comment: I know that people like to talk about attributes coupling code to frameworks, the same is said with Spring. Changing attributes in any decent IDE is pretty straight forward. It is your assumption to make if it is something you want to force.